# Is there any way to run test cases on different browser at once in robotframework using Ride

Tags: python, robotframework, cross-browser-testing, parallel-execution, ride

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}            https://www.youtube.com/
${browser}        chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Search
    [Template]
    Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}
    Maximize Browser Window
```

NOTE : If we want to run the above test case at the same time on different browsers. How can we handle it in robot framework (Is it possible to integrate with sauce labs / browser stack). Currently, I am passing the variable browser from command line. eg : `robot --variable BROWSER:Chrome Youtube.robot`

But I want to run it on different browsers at once.

Comment: you cannot run parallel tests in RIDE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Pabot**: [A parallel executor for Robot Framework tests](https://pabot.org/).

From their [GitHub page](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot). You can find more advanced use-cases and documentations here.

> Run same tests with two different configurations.
>
> ```
> pabot --argumentfile1 first.args --argumentfile2 second.args [path to tests]
> ```

I am not very familiar with RIDE, but I think you can configure Pabot as an [executor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65340896/3820025).

Answer (score 0):

I use Browserstack (not with RF), but let's see how you can do it. I believe similar approach might be possible with Sauce Labs.

First I need some variables:

```
*** Variables ***
${base_url}                    https://www.google.com/
${os}                          windows
${os_version}                  10
${browser}                     chrome
${browser_version}             84
${browserstack_username}       username
${browserstack_accesskey}      secret
```

You especially choose what OS and browser you want to run your tests in Browserstack: `${os}`, `${os_version}`, `${browser}`, and `${browser_version}`.

> Currently, I am passing the variable browser from command line.

You can keep doing it with the above-mentioned four variables.

Then you need to open a browser in Browserstack:

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser In Browserstack
    ${remoteUrl}                Set Variable        http://${browserstack_username}:${browserstack_accesskey}@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub
    &{desired_capabilities}      Create Dictionary   os=${os}     os_version=${os_version}     browser=${browser}   browser_version=${browser_version}
    Open Browser      ${baseUrl}    remote_url=${remote_url}     desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}
```

And so you can then put it all together:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary      

*** Variables ***
${base_url}                    https://www.google.com/
${os}                          windows
${os_version}                  10
${browser}                     chrome
${browser_version}             84
${browserstack_username}       username
${browserstack_accesskey}      secret

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser In Browserstack
    ${remoteUrl}                Set Variable        http://${browserstack_username}:${browserstack_accesskey}@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub
    &{desired_capabilities}      Create Dictionary   os=${os}     os_version=${os_version}     browser=${browser}   browser_version=${browser_version}
    Open Browser      ${baseUrl}    remote_url=${remote_url}     desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}

*** Test Cases *** 
Browserstack
    Open Browser In Browserstack
```

When I navigate to Browserstack, I can see my test:

[image]

I think this what I've shown is really all you need, but:

> to run the above test case at the same time

well, I feel you can use what's already available, e.g. [pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot). I have never tried this, so you can give it a try and let me know in the comment section if it works.